# Visual studio extension error?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

My newly installed Visual studio poped up a dialog box with the message of

> An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension.
>
> You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users....\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

And I found the following errors in the xml file.

> A MEF Component threw an exception at runtime: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliTrace.SourceControl.HistoricalModeHint.HistoricalModeTaggerProvider". ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Utilities, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliTrace.SourceControl.HistoricalModeHint.HistoricalModeTaggerProvider..ctor(SVsServiceProvider serviceProvider, IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService adapterFactory) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0()

and

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliTrace.SourceControl.HistoricalModeHint.HistoricalModeTaggerProvider". ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Utilities, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliTrace.SourceControl.HistoricalModeHint.HistoricalModeTaggerProvider..ctor(SVsServiceProvider serviceProvider, IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService adapterFactory) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.DelegateServices.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<As>b__0() at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.GatherTaggers(ITextBuffer textBuffer)

I tried to repair VS but it doesn't help. I also tried to force the cache to be rebuilt:

1. Delete the contents of the folder at "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache"
2. Run "DevEnv.exe /setup" (this is under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE", but should be on your PATH if you open a Developer Command Prompt).

Comment: You may wish to consider sending feedback if you haven't already through Help > Send Feedback. That'll collect some other logs and might give the team who owns this some clue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the VS with safe mode using the command: **devenv /safemode**, if it works fine, that means the installed extensions caused this issue, you can go to Tools—Extensions and Updates and click ‘Updates’ tab and install all updates, then reopen VS. Or click ‘Installed’ tab and remove/uninstall the installed extensions one by one to find the culprit.

Another thing you can try is to run visual studio as administrator, it can help us to excludes the permission issue.

Comment: It may be the permission issue. The installation reported two errors too and the log file shows there is no permission to access the installation service(?). My company doesn't let us install software using administrator permission. In stead we install using  "elevated" . I'm contacting IT but it may take a while and very frustrated. SQL server management studio 2016 even has more installation issues and cannot be installed. Is there a way to get around it? Why only the newer version of Microsoft products have the issues?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9, you can do nearly everything in the Visual Studio IDE as a normal user, but, you need administrator permissions to complete the tasks like Installation, Application types, Toolbox…., for more detail information, you can have a look at User Permissions and Visual Studio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj662724.aspx

Comment: I'm out of office right now. I sent the IT department a ticket for it not sure what they will do for the issue. I will check it on Monday.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9, this issue is gone or not? If not, you can share your current information in here.